# Ajax call using php file placed in theme folder in Osclass classified script?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, osclass

I am using Osclass classified script, trying to alert a message returned by ajax call.
My ajax-test.php file which is saved in my theme folder contains

```
<?php
$name = $_GET["name"];
echo "I am " . $name
?>
```

and my JavaScript function code is

```
function findName() {
    var name = "Jhon";
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
//        url: "oc-content/themes/bender/ajax-test.php",
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1/osclass/index.php?page=ajax&action=custom&ajaxfile=ajax-test.php',
        data: { name : name },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
    })
}
```

Anybody tell me what am I doing wrong? it alerts 
{"error" => "ajaxFile doesn't exist"}

Note: It works fine with commented line of code

Comment: try to change url to url: '../osclass/index.php?page=ajax&action=custom&ajaxfile=ajax-test.php', always detect data in the inspect element

Comment: why you sending  `ajax-test.php` php file in params ?

Comment: I am using Osclass classified script, It has its own ajax controller to handle ajax request.

Comment: Ajax request in Osclass classified script can be sent like this `/index.php?page=ajax&action=custom&ajaxfile=ajax-test.php` here we are telling the main controller that it is ajax call and we are using custom file which is `ajax-test.php`

Comment: The $.ajax **url** setting receives a string containing the url but I don't believe it will process the string as a http query. So you won't be able to pass parameters that way. Are you trying to use functions from another file? You could include something like `require_once 'index.php'` into your ajax-text.php file and call the functions from there.

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
>  method: "POST",
```

in ajax then why are you using GET ?

```
$name = $_GET["name"];
```

Using Post to getting value for it.

$name = $_POST["name"];

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelyn, that's not exactly how the ajax.php custom action works.

First, `page=ajax&action=custom` **doesn't work with themes**, only with plugins since it will search `ajaxfile` inside the plugins folder by doing something like this:

```
$filePath = osc_plugins_path() . $ajaxfile; // eg. /oc-content/plugins/$ajaxfile
```

You then have to pass in `ajaxfile` the name of the plugin to work. If you were using the Madhouse Messenger plugin, you would do something like:

```
page=ajax&action=custom&ajaxfile=madhouse_messenger/main.php
```

**However, since 3.3,** when using `page=ajax&action=custom`, you do not use the `ajaxfile` param anymore but the `route` param. You can take a look at [how routes work here](https://doc.osclass.org/Using_routes_in_Osclass) and [some examples of routes here](https://github.com/osclass/osclass-plugins/tree/routes_example).

Comment: thanks for reply,
I just wanted to go through the controller `index.php` when fetching data from database using ajax. My code is working fine if I make use of commented line of code i. e. `url: "oc-content/themes/bender/ajax-test.php",`.
As you can see in commented line of code `ajax-test.php` is used to fatch some date from database, do you recommend using ajax in this way?

Answer (score 0):

in your theme `functions.php`

add something like this:

```
//name of your custom ajax request
$my_custom_ajax_request_name = 'doSomethingCool';

osc_add_hook('ajax_' . $my_custom_ajax_request_name, $my_custom_ajax_request_name);

function doSomethingCool()
{
    // set default response
    $response = [
        'status' => false,
        'msg'    => 'Default Error Message...',
    ];

    // token protection
    // read more about csrf token:
    // https://dev.osclass.org/2013/02/19/make-your-plugins-more-secure-with-anti-csrf-functions/
    osc_csrf_check();

    // get request parameters
    $param1 = Params::getParam('param1');
    $param2 = Params::getParam('param2');

    // do some logic here ex: check if user is logged in
    if (osc_is_web_user_logged_in()) {
        $response['status'] = true;
        $response['msg']    = 'User is logged in. ;-) ' . $param1 . ' ' . $param2 . '! ' . osc_logged_user_name();
    } else {
        $response['status'] = false;
        $response['msg']    = 'User is not logged in. :-(';
    }

    // return json response
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
```

some where in your template files like `header.php`, `footer.php` or everything else you need it...

```
<a data-param1="hello" data-param2="world" href="#" id="make-an-ajax-request">
    Make an AJAX Request!
</a>
<script>
//here we hold some usefull info for easy access
    var mySite = window.mySite || {};
    mySite.base_url = '<?php echo osc_base_url(true); ?>';
    mySite.csrf_token = '<?php echo osc_csrf_token_url(); ?>';

    $(function(){

        $('#make-an-ajax-request').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            // name of our custom ajax hook 
            var ajax_hook = 'doSomethingCool';
            // get parameters
            var param1 = $(this).data('param1');
            var param2 = $(this).data('param2');
            // build axjxa url
            var url = mySite.base_url + '?page=ajax&action=runhook&hook='+ajax_hook+'&'+mySite.csrf_token;

            //build data 
            var data = {
                param1 : param1,
                param2 : param2
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: data,
                url: url
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.status) {

                } else {

                }
            });
        });

        });
</script>
```

---

### OSCLASS WAY

> to note that the current osclass way of doing an ajax request from a theme page is to call the
>   `http://example.com/?page=ajax&action=runhook&hook=MY_HOOK_FUNCTION_NAME`
>   and register it like `osc_add_hook('ajax_MY_HOOK_FUNCTION_NAME',
>   'MY_HOOK_FUNCTION_NAME');` optionally but very recommended is the use
>   of the `csrf token` that you can implement like i have done for url or
>   by calling the `osc_csrf_token_form()` directly into your form.

### NON OSCLASS WAY

> just create a file in your theme or everywhere you want and make sure to put this into it `<?php require_once __DIR__ . RELATIVE_PATH_TO_OC_LOAD_FILE . 'oc-load.php'; ?>` then build your logic into it.